# Creating an API for an AWS S3 upload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have about 200Gb of files on a Windows server file share that i want to upload in to S3. From looking at the documentation, it looks like i have to write my own API to do.

I'm an networking and server guy - I have no coding experience. Can anyone point me in the right direction for getting started? Has anyone ever done this before, who could maybe give me the high level overview of the steps involved, so that I can go an research each step? Any info will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What documentation are you looking at that makes you think you need to "create your own API"? All you need to do is download and install the AWS CLI tool for Windows, and then run an `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` command at the Windows command line to copy the files to S3. There are also options for PowerShell. Or are there more requirements than what you have listed in your question?

Comment: I use s3browser or tnt drive for that kind of tasks. No need to write your own API. You can even upload directly from the S3 management console.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed! i watched a YouTube video  that covered the CP command only. Thank you!